# React Native with CocoaPods, Error: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, react-native

I am using React Native 0.18 / XCode 7.2 and want to install a wrapper for a the Mixpanel SDK via [davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel: A React Native...](https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel)

This requires that I install the wrapper & then the SDK via CocoaPods - however I am always getting this error here:

> /Users/XXX/Documents/@Code - React
>   Native/PocketApp_redux/ios/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: line 62: /usr/local/bin/rsync: Bad CPU
>   type in executable Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

**This doesnt only happen with this repo, but with ALL wrappers for SDKs wich are installed via CocoaPods!**

What does this mean? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was actually in the given in the error: I had to remove `/usr/local/bin/rsync` which was from 2004 (PowerPC times)